# Plot value over hour of day with xts/zoo R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I do have a time-series looking like this (minute values):

```
   "timestamp", value 
    "2012-04-09 05:03:00",2
    "2012-04-09 05:04:00",4
    "2012-04-09 05:05:00",5
    "2012-04-09 05:06:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:07:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:08:00",3
    "2012-04-09 05:09:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:10:00",1
```

Is there an easy way to plot these values over the hour of the day: X-Axis from 1 to 24 hours (or 0 and 23). So - all values between 5:00 and 5:59 over the 5th hour etc.  It doesn't depend wich date, I am just interested in the houers of the day.
Thank you!

Additional Question: Can I plot this as a boxplot? Right now it's `plot(df$hh,df$coredata.._data..)`in zoo format.

Comment: You can get the hour with: `as.POSIXlt(DF$timestamp)$hour`. Then just do: `plot(., DF$value)` where `.` is the hours you obtain from POSIXlt object.

Comment: DF is already zoo with set as.POSIXct - so I get: "not possible for univariate zoo series".

Comment: @Arun - I was creating an answer that is exactly how you approach it in your comment and didn't see you had already commented

Comment: Not that familiar with `zoo` package, but maybe you can convert it first using `strptime` and then use `posixlt` as follows: `as.POSIXlt(strptime(tt.z$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))$hour`, where tt.z is the zoo object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xts` package, you can use `.indexhour` Generic functions  to  format the index of an xts object to hours.

For example , I read the data,

```
dat <- read.zoo(text='timestamp, value 
    "2012-04-09 05:03:00",2
    "2012-04-09 05:04:00",4
    "2012-04-09 05:05:00",5
    "2012-04-09 05:06:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:07:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:08:00",3
    "2012-04-09 05:09:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:10:00",1',header=TRUE,tz='',index=0:1,sep=',')

transform(dat, hh = .indexhour(dat))
                    coredata.._data.. hh
2012-04-09 05:03:00                 2  5
2012-04-09 05:04:00                 4  5
2012-04-09 05:05:00                 5  5
2012-04-09 05:06:00                 0  5
2012-04-09 05:07:00                 0  5
2012-04-09 05:08:00                 3  5
2012-04-09 05:09:00                 0  5
2012-04-09 05:10:00                 1  5
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the data creating zoo object `z` and then create `hour` variable and plot:

```
library(zoo)

# read in data
Lines <- ' "timestamp", value 
    "2012-04-09 05:03:00",2
    "2012-04-09 05:04:00",4
    "2012-04-09 05:05:00",5
    "2012-04-09 05:06:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:07:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:08:00",3
    "2012-04-09 05:09:00",0
    "2012-04-09 05:10:00",1
'
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", tz = "")

# plot
hour <- as.POSIXlt(time(z))$hour
plot(hour, z)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You could get a vector of the hours by converting those times to `POSIXlt` classes and then extracting the `"hours"` component from the resulting list for each one, using sapply to return a vector. You can then add this to the original dataframe:

```
df <- read.table( text = "timestamp, value 
    2012-04-09 05:03:00,2
    2012-04-09 05:04:00,4
    2012-04-09 05:05:00,5
    2012-04-09 05:06:00,0
    2012-04-09 05:07:00,0
    2012-04-09 05:08:00,3
    2012-04-09 05:09:00,0
    2012-04-09 05:10:00,1" , h = T , sep = "," )

# Convert to POSIX class
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXlt(df$timestamp)

# Each entry in timestamp has some hidden attributes
attributes(df$timestamp[1])
$names
# [1] "sec"   "min"   "hour"  "mday"  "mon"   "year"  "wday"  "yday"  "isdst"

hours <- sapply( seq_len( nrow( df ) ) , function(x) df$timestamp[x]$hour )

df$hours <- hours

df
#               timestamp value hours
#   1 2012-04-09 05:03:00     2     5
#   2 2012-04-09 05:04:00     4     5
#   3 2012-04-09 05:05:00     5     5
#   4 2012-04-09 05:06:00     0     5
#   5 2012-04-09 05:07:00     0     5
#   6 2012-04-09 05:08:00     3     5
#   7 2012-04-09 05:09:00     0     5
#   8 2012-04-09 05:10:00     1     5
```

Comment: Thank you - works good, but I do have the data already in zoo (merged), if I go back to as.data.frame(df) threre is no more date - can I read hour in date format from zoo as well (I set it by as.PPOISXct).

Comment: Can you set it by as.POSIXlt instead? Check Arun's comment under your question?

Comment: I am just getting NAs then... is there no way IN zoo or xts class?